# Entity Framework code first Automated Schema Migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, schema, code-first

Is there a way to do this with EF?

I want the schema to mutate dynamically to fit incoming DTOs. So essentially similar to what StreamInsight would be doing behind the scenes.

I don't want anyone to be touching the database directly, all modification etc. will be done by the program, on the fly. Not separately, via a primer script or visual studio macro, but automatically by the program itself based on the preset logic.

Another thing, all existing data must be kept, unless the modification calls for a column to be dropped. A referential integrity violation should be construed as a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be looking for EF Migrations, which are included in 4.3 and above.  There's an intro to EF migrations at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Yes that is similar. Except I want the automatic migration to happen during runtime, without interruption to the application itself. The code itself could change dynamically via sideloading, or reflection emit. Can the database change at runtime without deployment or interruption?

Comment: You could do this with FluentMigrations and the FluentMigrationRuntime. https://github.com/danielcrenna/fluent-migrator-runtime